# How do I determine the size, first STACK in java and delete data in between the STACK

Tags: java

I have 3 books from "A" to "C". How do I display them using a `Stack`, and then display its size. Also how do I delete book "B" and then be able to display the size again?

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test_stack {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push(“a”);
        printStack(stack);
        stack.push(“b”);
        printStack(stack);
        stack.push(“c”);
        printStack(stack);

        stack.pop();
        printStack(stack);
        stack.pop();
        printStack(stack);
        stack.pop();
        printStack(stack);
    }

    private static void printStack(Stack<String> s){
        if(s.isEmpty())
            System.out.printIn(“empty stack”);
        else
            System.out.printf(“% s TOP\n”, s);
    }

}
```

The output I'm getting is :

```
[a] TOP
[a, b] TOP
[a, b, c] TOP
[a, b] TOP
[a] TOP
empty stack
```

I want to achieve:

```
[a,b,c] TOP
[a,c] TOP
empty stack
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that with a stack? If you need access to the elements in the middle use a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

Though I would recommend you to use a different data structure like `linked list` if you want to delete from middle because that's what `linked lists` are for. You should NOT AT ALL use stacks if the requirement is to delete an element from middle. But since the question asks for it, then you can introduce a method `deleteFrom()` as displayed below.

This method will take two arguments, the stack and the object to be deleted and if that object is present in the stack, then it would be deleted.

**Output**

```
[a] TOP
[a, b] TOP
[a, b, c] TOP

After calling deleteFrom(stack, "b")
[a, c] TOP
```

**deleteFrom() method code:**

```
public static Stack<String> deleteFrom(Stack<String> stack, String obj) {
    if (stack.search(obj) == -1) {
        System.out.println("Element doesn't exists in stack.");
        return stack;
    }
    Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<String>();
    while (stack.search(obj) != -1)
        stack2.push(stack.pop());
    stack2.pop();
    while (stack2.size() != 0)
        stack.push(stack2.pop());
    return stack;
}
```

---

*The final code would look like:*

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push("a");
        printStack(stack);
        stack.push("b");
        printStack(stack);
        stack.push("c");
        printStack(stack);

        stack = deleteFrom(stack, "b");
        System.out.println("After calling deleteFrom(stack, \"b\")");
        printStack(stack);
    }

    private static void printStack(Stack<String> s) {
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("empty stack");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s TOP\n", s);
        }
    }

    public static Stack<String> deleteFrom(Stack<String> stack, String obj) {
        if (stack.search(obj) == -1) {
            System.out.println("Element doesn't exists in stack.");
            return stack;
        }
        Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<String>();
        while (stack.search(obj) != -1)
            stack2.push(stack.pop());
        stack2.pop();
        while (stack2.size() != 0)
            stack.push(stack2.pop());
        return stack;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this can be done using general stack operations of **push** and **pop**. Remember stack is LIFO. So in order to remove(POP) b, you have to remove(POP) c. And then again you have to push c.

Edit: If you manage to accomplish the required goal, be rest assured that you did not use the concept of stacks. Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using `Stack` because that violates the whole concept of `Stack` operations. Even if we come up with a function that would remove an element from the middle of stack, then behind the scenes, it would be removing all the above elements > remove the required element > Push back the above elements again. And definitely this isn't a good approach.

The concept that stack uses is different. But if you have a scenario where you've to delete an element from middle, then you should be using `LinkedList` instead of `Stack`. That's what `LinkedList` basically is for.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.*;

public class LinkedListDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // create a LinkedList
       LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

       // add some elements
       list.add("A");
       list.add("B");
       list.add("C");

       // print the list
       System.out.println("LinkedList:" + list);
       System.out.println("size:" + list.size());

       // remove "B" Element from the list
       list.remove("B");

       // print the list
       System.out.println("LinkedList:" + list);
       System.out.println("size:" + list.size());
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
LinkedList:[A, B, C]
size: 3
LinkedList:[A, C]
size: 2
```

Comment: It is possible by popping items off and adding them back on. Agreed, probably not the best idea in some circumstances - but still it is possible.

Comment: I agree that it's possible and your answer explains it well. All that I'm saying is that if it's possible, then use a different data structure bacause `stacks` aren't for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove `b` from your stack, you would need to pop all the books off the stack and push them onto a temporary stack until you got to `b`, then pop all the books off the temporary stack and push them back on the main stack.

For example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test_stack {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        // put a, b and c on the stack
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push(“a”);
        stack.push(“b”);
        stack.push(“c”);
        printStack(stack);

        // pop items off the stack until we reach b (and push non b items onto temporary stack)
        Stack<String> temporaryStack = new Stack<String>();
        String currentItem;
        do {
            currentItem = stack.pop();
            if(!currentItem.equals("b")) {
                temporaryStack.push(currentItem);
        } while(!currentItem.equals("b"));

        // push temporary stack back onto main stack
        while(!temporaryStack.isEmpty()) {
            stack.push(temporaryStack.pop());
        }
        printStack(stack);
    }

    private static void printStack(Stack<String> s){
        if(s.isEmpty())
            System.out.printIn(“empty stack”);
        else
            System.out.printf(“% s TOP\n”, s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of `Stack` using `LinkedList` using adapter design pattern, you have to both push/pop at either head or tail to get Stack

```
public class StackLL<E> {

    private LinkedList<E> list;

    public StackLL() {
        list = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        list.addFirst(e);
    }

    public E pop(E e) {
        Iterator<E> it = list.descendingIterator(); // list.iterator()
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            E ele = it.next();
            if (ele == e) {
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public E pop() {
        return list.removeFirst();
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

In this implementation the underlying data structure is still a double linked list, so you can have your custom methods to do some special operations, in your case it is to search and delete an element, so I have overloaded pop method with an element which is to be deleted, it does an iteration and deletes the matching one element else returns null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackLL<String> stack = new StackLL<>();
    stack.push("a");
    stack.push("b");
    stack.push("c");
    stack.print();
    stack.pop("b");
    stack.print();
    stack.pop("b");
}
```

Output

```
[c, b, a]
[c, a]
```

In case if you want to delete mid element, you can simply have an Element as member variable, after every 2 pushes you can increment it one position up also after every 2 pops you can decrement one position down with just O(1) complexity.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a second temporary stack to hold the values above the element you want to remove:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
stack.push("a");
stack.push("b");
stack.push("c");

// Pop the elements from the original stack onto
// the temporary stack.
Stack<String> temp = new Stack<String>();
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    String top = stack.pop();
    if (top.equals("b")) {
        break;
    }
    temp.push(top);
}

// Pop the elements from the temporary stack
// back into the original stack. This preserves
// the original order.
while (!temp.isEmpty()) {
    stack.push(temp.pop());
}
```